# Apollo cache is not updating after the mutation

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

Apollo cache is not updating after the mutation, I don't want to manually access the cache so writeQuery and readQuery method to update cache is out of the picture.
update method with readQuery and writeQuery was updating the cache but that is not how I want it to update. I want it to get update automatically.
I used refetchQueries also, API was called and I was getting the fresh data from the server as response but it's not updating the cache and cache still have old data.
I called query to fetch fresh data after executing the mutation but it was returning me stale data from cache. fetch-policy is **cache-and-network**.
Here is how I want things to work:
After executing mutation I will call query to the server to get the fresh data and it should update the cache with fresh data.

```
async deleteFamilyMember () {
      await this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          mutation: DELETE_FAMILY_MEMBER,
          variables: {
            familyMemberId: this.memberToDelete
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.getFamilyMembers()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

 async getFamilyMembers () {
      await this.$apollo
        .query({
          query: FAMILY_MEMBERS
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.familyMembers = response.data.familyMembers
          this.$store.commit('SET_FAMILY_MEMBERS', response.data.familyMembers)
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log('Error fetching family members details', err)
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this.$apollo.query() use this.$apollo.watchQuery()
The watchQuery method returns a QueryRef object which has the value changes property that is an Observable.
The observable will only emit once when the query is complete, and loading will be set to false unless you set the watchQuery parameters notifyOnNetworkStatusChange to true.Once the query has completed, it will also contain a data object.
So if some other query fetches new information, this component will update to remain consistent.

For more read [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries/)

```
      await this.$apollo
        .watchQuery({
          query: FAMILY_MEMBERS
        })
        .subscribe({
          next: ({ data }) => {
            console.log("DATA", data);
            this.familyMembers = data.familyMembers;
            this.$store.commit(SET_FAMILY_MEMBERS, data.familyMembers);
          },
          error: e => console.error("Error fetching family members details", e)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Happy to help :)